# Как передать функцию внутри функции?

Tags: javascript

Делаю так

```
var f;
function go(fi){fi("1"); setTimeout('f = "'+fi+'"',1000);}
go(alert);
console.log(typeof("f"));
```

На выходе мне надо получить функцию f, а я получаю строку.
Подскажите, как сделать правильно

Answer (score 1):

Вот эта конструкция:

```
setTimeout('f = "'+fi+'"',1000);
```

работает так:

1. вычисляем параметр: `'f = "'+fi+'"'` -> `'f = "' + alert + '"'` -> `'f = "function alert() {
   [native code]
   }"'`. Заметьте, что `fi` превратился в текстовое описание функции.
2. Ждем 1000 мс.
3. Выполняем в глобальном скоупе `eval()` от полученной строчки.

Лучше взять за правило [избегать передачу кода в виде текста в setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout), а передавать туда функцию:

```
var f;
function go(fi) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    f = fi;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Вложенная анонимная функция будет так называемой ["closure"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures): в ней доступны переменные из функции `go()`, в которую она вложена.

Answer (score 0):

Ну так у Ваc же f - это переменная, а не функция.
Напишите функцию f
(конкретно здесь передаётся переменная, а не функция)

```
function f(fi){alert("i am f with "+fi)}
function go(fi){SetTimeout(f(fi),1000);}  //через секунду запустится f(fi)

go("text");
```

Comment: Т.е. должно быть так, но название функции должно передаваться в параметре функции go

<!-- language: lang-js -->
var f;
function go(fi){fi("1"); setTimeout('f = alert',1000);}
go(alert);
f("2");<!-- language: lang-js -->